# How to extract text related to a regular expression (regexpr) index in R

Tags: r, regex, sequence

I'm working with a specialised text file, which is essentially a long list of names and random sequence of letters associated to each name. I'm attempting to extract a particular consensus sequence I'm interesting in. The sequence is, lets say "STXDXIK", with X being any letter. I red the text file into R and named it "TEXT".

Then i used regular expression to isolate the list of entries containing the sequence, calling it "ylist".

```
ylist<- TEXT[grep("ST[A-Z]D[A-Z]IK", TEXT, value=FALSE, perl=FALSE)]
```

Then i used the regexpr function to locate the position of the sequence I'm interested in, calling it "r".

```
r<- regexpr("ST[A-Z]D[A-Z]IK", ylist)
```

Now the problem is that I get an index of locations that this sequence lies in, with the starting position and number of matches. However I'm interested in extracting the full sequences, and not the indexes from "ylist" since its important to me what the full length sequence is. can anyone help?

I have tried substr and regmatches functions in R but substr has to be applied for each match, which is not practical for me as I have many many matches with this sequence and regmatches don't seem to work or I can't make it work, perhaps because I enter a wrong command.

Comment: Why do you create `ylist`? Isn't `r <- regexpr("ST[A-z]D[A-z]IK", TEXT)` enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a for-loop:

```
TEXT <- c("tedSTXDXIKsslker","janetlkajsdfSTXDXIKalkse","maggiesdfes","sdfjkSTXDXIKryan")
ylist<- grep("ST[A-Z]D[A-Z]IK", TEXT, value=TRUE, perl=FALSE)

r<- regexpr("ST[A-Z]D[A-Z]IK", ylist)

strings <- character()
for(i in seq_along(ylist)){strings <- c(strings,substr(ylist[i],start=r[i],stop=r[i]+6))}

> strings
[1] "STXDXIK" "STXDXIK" "STXDXIK"
```

Or in one line using the `stringr` package.

```
require(stringr)
> str_extract(string=TEXT,pattern="ST[A-Z]D[A-Z]IK")
[1] "STXDXIK" "STXDXIK" NA        "STXDXIK"

strings2 <- str_extract(string=TEXT,pattern="ST[A-Z]D[A-Z]IK")
strings2 <- strings2[!is.na(strings2)]
> strings2
[1] "STXDXIK" "STXDXIK" "STXDXIK"
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, it works! Also the for-loop can allow me to look at the flanking sequences surrounding my sequence by simply adding positive or negative numbers to the substr section.

Answer (score 3):

You could combine `regexpr` and `substr`:

```
TEXT <- c("tedSTXDXIKsslker","janetlkajsdfSTXDXIKalkse","maggiesdfes","sdfjkSTXDXIKryan")
r <- regexpr("ST[A-z]D[A-z]IK", TEXT)
s <- substr(TEXT, r, r+attr(r, "match.length")-1)
s
# [1] "STXDXIK" "STXDXIK" ""        "STXDXIK"
```

If you want to filter the `""` you could use:

```
s <- s[nchar(s)>0]
# [1] "STXDXIK" "STXDXIK" "STXDXIK"
```

EDIT: add `gregexpr` example

```
TEXT <- c("tedSTXDXIKsslker","janetlkajsdfSTXDXIKalkse","maggiesdfes","sdfjkSTXDXIKryan",
      "sdfjkSTXDXIKryansdfjkSTXDXIKryan")
## use gregexpr instead of regexpr
r <- gregexpr("ST[A-z]D[A-z]IK", TEXT)
## because gregexpr returns a list, we have to use mapply (or a for loop)
## please note: I use substring instead of substr here because substr returns only a vector of the same size as the input vector.
mapply(FUN=function(str, rx)substring(str, rx, rx+attr(rx, "match.length")-1), str=TEXT, rx=r)

# $tedSTXDXIKsslker
# [1] "STXDXIK"
# 
# $janetlkajsdfSTXDXIKalkse
# [1] "STXDXIK"
# 
# $maggiesdfes
# [1] ""
# 
# $sdfjkSTXDXIKryan
# [1] "STXDXIK"
# 
# $sdfjkSTXDXIKryansdfjkSTXDXIKryan
# [1] "STXDXIK" "STXDXIK"
```

Comment: Nice. I initially thought `regexpr` returned a list, so when I tryied to pass it to `substr` I was trying to index the location and length as elements of the list - obviously that did not work. I am glad I see how to use it more efficiently now!

Comment: @sgibb Many thanks for this, it works! Also this is a very nice way of combining substr and regexpr! Just wondering how I could modify the above script to account for multiple sequence matches within a single entry? I tried gregexpr in the "r" argument above, which gives me the correct indexes for multiple sequence matches but the "s" argument doesn't work!

Comment: @Bez: `gregexpr` returns a list. That's why we have to use a for loop or `mapply`. Please see my edit.